# how to use weight when training a weak learner for adaboost

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost

The following is adaboost algorithm:
[image]

It mentions "using weights wi on the training data" at part 3.1.

I am not very clear about how to use the weights. Should I resample the training data?

Comment: Why downvote? What's wrong with my question? Please tell me so that I can correct it.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but maybe you can write the few points into a real markup listing instead of an image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I am not very clear about how to use the weights. Should I resample the training data?

It depends on what classifier you are using.

If your classifier can take instance weight (weighted training examples) into account, then you don't need to resample the data. An example classifier could be naive bayes classifier that accumulates weighted counts or a weighted k-nearest-neighbor classifier.

Otherwise, you want to resample the data using the instance weight, i.e., those instance with more weights could be sampled multiple times; while those instance with little weight might not even appear in the training data. Most of the other classifiers fall in this category.

### In Practice

Actually in practice, boosting performs better if you only rely on a pool of very naive classifiers, e.g., decision stump, linear discriminant. In this case, the algorithm you listed has a easy-to-implement form (see [here](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/scsjso/adaboost_talk.pdf) for details):
[image] Where alpha is chosen by (epsilon is defined similarly as yours).

[image]

### An Example

> Define a two-class problem in the plane (for example, a circle of points
>   inside a square) and build a strong classier out of a pool of randomly
>   generated linear discriminants of the type sign(ax1 + bx2 + c).

The two class labels are represented with red crosses and blue dots. We here are using a bunch of linear discriminants (yellow lines) to construct the pool of naive/weak classifiers. We generate 1000 data points for each class in the graph (inside the circle or not) and 20% of data is reserved for testing.

[image]

This is the classification result (in the test dataset) I got, in which I used 50 linear discriminants. The training error is 1.45% and the testing error is 2.3%

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! You said `random linear discriminants`, but how do you make sure each weak learner meets the `error rate < 0.5` constraint? Can you clarify on this/or post some code? Thanks!

Comment: check the slides here - page 8 to 10 (http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Courses//Fall2005//Lecture4-2.pdf). One thing you want to consider: this is an incremental model, at each step, we only need to pay more attention to these wrongly classified examples. Yes it is a linear discriminant, but those examples that have huge weights needs to be classified correctly this time, not those examples that have little weights. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where exactly is D(i) used?

Answer (score 0):

The weights are the values applied to each example (sample) in step 2. These weights are then updated at step 3.3 (wi).

So initially all weights are equal (step 2) and they are increased for wrongly classified data and decreased for correctly classified data. So in step 3.1 you have to take take these value in account to determine a new classifier, giving more importance to higher weight values. If you did not change the weight you would produce exactly the same classifier each time you execute step 3.1.

These weights are only used for training purpose, they're not part of the final model.